# Mostrar secuencia de imágenes en gtk3

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk

Requiero mostrar una secuencia de imágenes al presionar un botón. Primero se carga una imágen y un segundo después se carga la siguiente y así sucesivamente. Sin embargo, al presionar el botón solo me muestra la última imagen.

Este es mi código:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import time
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk


class GridWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="NEOTECH")
        self.grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(self.grid)

        self.btnStartTest=Gtk.Button("Iniciar Prueba")
        self.btnStartTest.connect("clicked",self.StartTest)

        self.image = Gtk.Image()
        self.image.set_from_file("logo-NeoTech.png")

        self.grid.add(self.btnStartTest)
        self.grid.attach(self.image,0,1,1,1)


    def StartTest(self,widget):
        self.image.set_from_file("gato3.jpg")
        time.sleep(2)
        self.image.set_from_file("gato4.jpg")
        print("fin")


win = GridWindow()
win.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
win.set_default_size(1000,480)
win.set_type_hint(Gdk.WindowTypeHint.MENU)
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Nunca se debe usar `time.sleep()` en una GUI** ya sea usando *gtk*, *pyqt*, *Kivy*, *Tkinter* o cualquier otro framework, a no ser que lo gestiones con hilos. `time.sleep()` es bloqueante, lo cual causa que durante este periodo de tiempo la interfaz deje de responder al bloquearse el mainloop encargado de actualizarla.

Los frameworks proporcionan métodos alternativos para hacer este tipo de cosas. En este caso puedes recurrir a [`GLib.timeout_add_seconds`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygobject/glib-functions.html#function-glib--timeout-add-seconds) y a un iterador. Al pulsar el botón creas un iterador sobre las imágenes (sus rutas), consumes el primer elemento inmediatamente (la primera imagen se muestra nada más pulsar el botón) y a continuación el resto las procesas mediante una función que será ejecutada periódicamente por `GLib.timeout_add_seconds` hasta agotar todas las imágenes del iterador:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GLib


class GridWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="NEOTECH")
        self.grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(self.grid)

        self.btnStartTest=Gtk.Button("Iniciar Prueba")
        self.btnStartTest.connect("clicked",self.StartTest)

        self.image = Gtk.Image()
        self.image.set_from_file("logo-NeoTech.png")

        self.grid.add(self.btnStartTest)
        self.grid.attach(self.image,0,1,1,1)


    def StartTest(self,widget):
        images= iter(("gato3.jpg","gato4.jpg", "gato3.jpg"))
        self.image.set_from_file(next(images))
        GLib.timeout_add_seconds(2, self.showImages, images )

    def showImages(self, images):
        img = next(images, None)
        if img:
            self.image.set_from_file(img)
            return True



win = GridWindow()
win.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
win.set_default_size(1000,480)
win.set_type_hint(Gdk.WindowTypeHint.MENU)
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Si quisieras reproducir un carrousel de imágenes indefinidamente puedes usar [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
import itertools    

def StartTest(self,widget):
    images= itetools.cycle(("gato3.jpg","gato4.jpg"))
    self.image.set_from_file(next(images))
    GLib.timeout_add_seconds(2, self.showImages, images )
```